# Can definite integral be of the form $\int_{h(x)}^{g(x)}F'(x)dx exist$?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

In theory, I can write down an integral of the form
$$I(x)=\int_{h(x)}^{g(x)}F'(x)dx$$
and solve it as
$$I(x)=F(g(x))-F(h(x))$$
Out of curiosity, I plugged this into my calculator and was given a message saying that the integral was unsolvable because it contained a "dependent bound".

What's wrong with an integral containing a "dependent bound"? Is it merely a problem with the calculator?

Comment: If you change the variable of $F'$ to $t$ and $dx$ to $dt$ you will be fine.

Comment: Firstly, you should **really** avoid using a variable in limits and as a variable of integration. Secondly, it's probably because a TI-89 and its ilk cannot handle such generalities. They can do definite integrals and *explicit* antiderivatives no problem, but they're not hard-coded to do theory.

Comment: So it's really just an issue with me incorrectly inputting a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insteatd of
$$I(x)=\int_{h(x)}^{g(x)}F'(\color{blue}{x})\,\mathrm d\color{blue}{x}$$
You should have used something like this

$$I(x)=\int_{h(x)}^{g(x)}F'(\color{red}{t})\,\mathrm d\color{red}{t}$$

The notation you've used is ugly

Comment: Okay, I'll just substitute in $t$ next time.